# Drawing on JFreeChart after it has been created

Tags: java, annotations, jfreechart

I am doing a school project and I've been stuck with this problem for a week. I can't figure out how to annotate jfreechart after it has been created.

Right now the program looks like this -> [image: My program]

User should be able to draw lines or add strings on the chart with a mouse click. Does someone know how to do this?

How I have extended ChartPanel:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;

public class ExChartPanel extends ChartPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
String txt="Can add Strings before creating chart";

public ExChartPanel(JFreeChart chart){
    super(chart);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString(txt, 100, 100);
}

public void setTxt(String txt) {
    this.txt = txt;
    repaint();
}}
```

Now when I run I can draw strings before the chart is made... But if on a main frame button is pressed to call setTxt("some txt"), it does not update text on panel.
Same goes with lines and other shapes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend `JFree ChartPanel` to add this functionality.

Your extended class should capture user actions, create annotations and add it to underlying JFreeChart using `XYPlot.addAnnotation`.

As described in [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/index.html) API documentation, the chart will be redrawn automatically whenever any change notification is received.

Also, refer to `ChartPanel` source code to understand the API better and build your class on top of those APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I put up an example of my ChartPanel extension which does not work... how to edit it?